# Code highlighting in content and code display in WYSIWYG editor

Tags: wysiwyg, highlighting

I'm developing a website right now and what I've came across now is a possibility to display code in content - HTML, JavaScript, CSS, PHP, ActionScript or whatever. I'm developing the website using CodeIgniter. I have found a plugin to do it, but unfortunately it doesn't work, it also doesn't output any errors. So, what I'm asking for - how to display the code normally in content of my website? And also, I'm of course gonna have an admin panel for all that, and for adding articles a WYSIWYG editor will be used. How do I make sure that if I copy PHP or whatever code in there, it doesn't wrap it with WYSIWIG editors HTML tags? Thanks in advance, ask for more details if You could know the answer but don't understand my question completely.

Regards, Ed

Answer (score 1):

How about using [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for syntax highlighting? It has a really high development activity and uses just JavaScript and CSS. All code is wrapped into `<pre>` tags. In order to print XML-like code, you need to escape some symbols like `<` with its [entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference). I never used CodeIgniter, but I guess it has the needed abilities.

Comment: thanks for your reply! well, it solves at least something - highlighting is ok. but, it only works if i haven't wrapped it in PHP tags, which sometimes may be used in the code samples. also, how to deal with the wysiwyg editor issue?

Comment: @Eduards: What do you mean by "wrapped in PHP tags"? And what exactly is the WYSIWYG issue? You need to describe a more precise scenario and maybe show some code that you're struggling with in your question.